# Three js 2d matrix visualization

Tags: three.js, webgl, data-visualization

I am trying to visualize 2d matrices using Three js. These matrices are the states of the neurons in a neural network. The matrices are not huge (64 x 32) The values in these matrices will change and I want those new values to be displayed in the visualization.

For the 2d matrix I want a plane of neurons.

I have tried creating a particle system using a plane geometry with as many vertices as neurons in the data matrix.

```
var width = 32;
var height = 64;
var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( width, height, width - 1 , height - 1 );
var particlePlane = new THREE.ParticleSystem( planeGeometry, shaderMaterial );
```

In the fragment shader each particle is given a base texture (a white circle)

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(baseTexture, gl_PointCoord);
```

And then I use a second texture containing the data matrix values (greyscale pixel values) to modify each base texture.

```
// Sets particle texture to desired color
// vertexPosition is a vec2 in coordinates local to the plane
gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D( dataTexture, vertexPosition );
```

To calculate vertexPosition in the vertex share I do the following (irrelevant lines ommitted):

```
uniform float width;
uniform float height;
varying vec2 vertexPosition;

void main() 
{
    vertexPosition = vec2( position.x / width, position.y / height );
}
```

This is where I'm getting caught up. The vertexPosition does not seem to be mapping properly to the dataTexture pixels. I want a one to one correspondence between particles and pixels.

How do I properly map from the location of particles/vertexes on a plane to equivalent pixel locations in a texture?

I am new to three js, so please feel free to tell me my approach is totally off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get texture coordinates, there are ready to use projection matrix in glsl, here is what I would use as a vertex shader

```
varying vec2 vertexPosition;

void main() {
  vertexPosition = uv;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Then you have the xy position to use in the fragment in the varying vertexPosition.

Comment: For future debugging how can I see the value of uv for each vertex?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764785/debug-glsl-code-in-webgl