# Any way to debug WebGL GLSL code embedded in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

I'm trying to learn about using particles using Sketch.js and came across this example, which I am trying to rework:

http://soulwire.github.io/Plasmatic-Isosurface/

The snippet of code in question is this hot mess:

```
GLSL = {
vert: "\n#ifdef GL_ES\nprecision mediump float;\n#endif\n\n// Uniforms\nuniform vec2 u_resolution;\n\n// Attributes\nattribute vec2 a_position;\n\nvoid main() {\n    gl_Position = vec4 (a_position, 0, 1);\n}\n",
frag: "\n#ifdef GL_ES\nprecision mediump float;\n#endif\n\nuniform bool u_scanlines;\nuniform vec2 u_resolution;\n\nuniform float u_brightness;\nuniform float u_blobiness;\nuniform float u_particles;\nuniform float u_millis;\nuniform float u_energy;\n\n\nfloat noise( vec2 co ){\n    return fract( sin( dot( co.xy, vec2( 12.9898, 78.233 ) ) ) * 43758.5453 );\n}\n\nvoid main( void ) {\n\n    vec2 position = ( gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution.x );\n    float t = u_millis * 0.001 * u_energy;\n    \n    float a = 0.0;\n    float b = 0.0;\n    float c = 0.0;\n\n    vec2 pos, center = vec2( 0.5, 0.5 * (u_resolution.y / u_resolution.x) );\n    \n    float na, nb, nc, nd, d;\n    float limit = u_particles / 40.0;\n    float step = 1.0 / u_particles;\n    float n = 0.0;\n    \n    for ( float i = 0.0; i <= 1.0; i += 0.025 ) {\n\n        if ( i <= limit ) {\n\n            vec2 np = vec2(n, 1-1);\n            \n            na = noise( np * 1.1 );\n            nb = noise( np * 2.8 );\n            nc = noise( np * 0.7 );\n            nd = noise( np * 3.2 );\n\n            pos = center;\n            pos.x += sin(t*na) * cos(t*nb) * tan(t*na*0.15) * 0.3;\n            pos.y += tan(t*nc) * sin(t*nd) * 0.1;\n            \n            d = pow( 1.6*na / length( pos - position ), u_blobiness );\n            \n            if ( i < limit * 0.3333 ) a += d;\n            else if ( i < limit * 0.6666 ) b += d;\n            else c += d;\n\n            n += step;\n        }\n    }\n    \n    vec3 col = vec3(a*c,b*c,a*b) * 0.0001 * u_brightness;\n    \n    if ( u_scanlines ) {\n        col -= mod( gl_FragCoord.y, 2.0 ) < 1.0 ? 0.5 : 0.0;\n    }\n    \n    gl_FragColor = vec4( col, 1.0 );\n\n}\n"};
```

The shaders are a weird embedded bit of GLSL, which I can't figure out how to debug. This specific issue that I can't quite understand is how the colours are set. The `col` variable seems to be a 4-dimensional vector, but it looks like it could be built up with 2-dimensional vectors. I don't really understand what's going on, which leads to the issue that I'm asking about here, which is, is there any way to debug such an embedded bit of code?

I've tried a Chrome extension called WebGL Insight, but that doesn't recognise the GLSL code, and I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for. There is this answer to a similar question ([Debug GLSL code in webgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764785/debug-glsl-code-in-webgl)) but I don't find it helpful. Do I need to break the shader out and use an external compiler? (And in that case, what software and libraries do I need?)

Comment: Please don't change my British spellings >:-(

Comment: The shader language is called [GLSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language), and while it looks like C, it is about as related to C as JavaScript is to Java. You'll have better luck rewording the question and tagging [tag:glsl] instead of [tag:c]

Comment: Thanks @Kninnug :-)

Comment: This might be helpful for some people seeking help for similar problems. It checks syntax, but does not have a debugger: https://www.shadertoy.com/new

Comment: There's [a shader editor for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shader-editor/ggeaidddejpbakgafapihjbgdlbbbpob?hl=en) that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mhh, simply reintroducing the line breaks results in quite the readable code:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform bool u_scanlines;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;

uniform float u_brightness;
uniform float u_blobiness;
uniform float u_particles;
uniform float u_millis;
uniform float u_energy;


float noise( vec2 co ){
    return fract( sin( dot( co.xy, vec2( 12.9898, 78.233 ) ) ) * 43758.5453 );
}

void main( void ) {

    vec2 position = ( gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution.x );
    float t = u_millis * 0.001 * u_energy;

    float a = 0.0;
    float b = 0.0;
    float c = 0.0;

    vec2 pos, center = vec2( 0.5, 0.5 * (u_resolution.y / u_resolution.x) );

    float na, nb, nc, nd, d;
    float limit = u_particles / 40.0;
    float step = 1.0 / u_particles;
    float n = 0.0;

    for ( float i = 0.0; i <= 1.0; i += 0.025 ) {

        if ( i <= limit ) {

            vec2 np = vec2(n, 1-1);

            na = noise( np * 1.1 );
            nb = noise( np * 2.8 );
            nc = noise( np * 0.7 );
            nd = noise( np * 3.2 );

            pos = center;
            pos.x += sin(t*na) * cos(t*nb) * tan(t*na*0.15) * 0.3;
            pos.y += tan(t*nc) * sin(t*nd) * 0.1;

            d = pow( 1.6*na / length( pos - position ), u_blobiness );

            if ( i < limit * 0.3333 ) a += d;
            else if ( i < limit * 0.6666 ) b += d;
            else c += d;

            n += step;
        }
    }

    vec3 col = vec3(a*c,b*c,a*b) * 0.0001 * u_brightness;

    if ( u_scanlines ) {
        col -= mod( gl_FragCoord.y, 2.0 ) < 1.0 ? 0.5 : 0.0;
    }

    gl_FragColor = vec4( col, 1.0 );

}
```

As this seems to be a screenspace shader one can use things like [glsl-sandbox](http://glsl-sandbox.com) or [shadertoy](http://shadertoy.com) to play around with it, just remap and/or substitute the unknown uniforms with defines:

```
//uniform bool u_scanlines;
#define u_scanlines false

//uniform float u_brightness;
#define u_brightness 1.
//uniform float u_blobiness;
#define u_blobiness 1.
//uniform float u_particles;
#define u_particles 20.
//uniform float u_millis;
#define u_millis 1.
//uniform float u_energy;
#define u_energy 1.

//uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 resolution;
#define u_resolution resolution
```

[image: voila]

To debug "in app" your only ready made solution is [Firefoxs Shader-Editor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Shader_Editor) as mentinoed by Tolokoban. As to other more sophisticated tools, there are the desktop shader debuggers like [NVIDIAs FX Composer](https://developer.nvidia.com/fx-composer), [AMDs RenderMonkey](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/archive/games-cgi/rendermonkey-toolsuite/) and [GLSL-Debugger(formerly GLSLDevil)](https://github.com/GLSL-Debugger/GLSL-Debugger).

Comment: Reading the code is not the issue (the first thing I did was pop it in a text editor and reformatted it). Understanding what unfamiliar things are doing is the hard part.

Comment: I did try Shadertoy, but it had a problem with vert and frag, and if I tried just the frag part I got noise. There's probably a way to input it into shadertoy in a way it understands but it's not readily apparent.

Comment: *You* were calling the shaders a "mess" a "weird bit of embedded GLSL", which they're clearly not. I gave you all the tools and techniques available for debugging, I even created the live code thing for you and set it up with some sensible variables. This is all if not more you asked for, if this doesn't help you then you might want to create another question and precisely state where you're stuck in understanding the code.

Comment: @LJ To be clear, I want to know if there is a tool to debug this fragment of code.  As in, pause execution, and see values in variables, or minimally print to the console, that type of thing. I have no problem reading the text of the code, I have an issue testing my assumptions and hypothesis about what is going on. I'm not asking anyone to solve the specific issue I'm trying to understand.

GLSL debugger is the only option I have for an actual debugger as the rest are Windows based. When I have more time I will try that out.

Comment: You can't, at least not in javascript / webgl applications as step debugging requires proprietary vendor specific integration which to my knowledge only [NVIDIAs Nsight](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nsight.html) provides(requires you to have an NVIDIA GPU and supported IDE). As it was outlined in the other question you linked, the fastest, easiest and pretty much only way to test your assumptions is to use color output or pen and paper.

Comment: Making this the answer since it included the desktop debuggers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this can help, but in Firefox, you can see the code of all shaders used in a web page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Shader_Editor.

Comment: This is very useful to know about. It sped up the "poking it with a stick" process since you can make changes in real time. Also nice that it gives good feedback on syntax errors. This ultimately helped me solve the problem.

Comment: For Chrome Shader Editor has worked for me: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shader-editor/ggeaidddejpbakgafapihjbgdlbbbpob?hl=en

Comment: Unfortunatly, Firefox has decided to deprecate this tool:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Deprecated_tools#Shader_editor